# Accessing private repo from docker using ssh keys generated with passphrase

Tags: docker, bitbucket

We have a private repo in bitbucket and we were trying to access it via npm and were able to do both git clone and npm install locally. But when we try to do the same in docker container, it threw an error saying `'Host key verification failed'` so we had to add  `known_hosts`( this is the one which lets client authenticate the server) which solved the problem and then it threw an other error saying `Permission denied (publickey)` and we had to add `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` keys, so what we did was we created a folder(because to access .ssh folder we need sudo cmd, which we don't want use) in machine with all three keys and in docker file using bash script we are trying to fetch these keys and copy to repository and pass same to docker while running the docker (removing ssh keys after finishing , as we don't want to keep keys in repository) container and it still threw an error saying `Permission denied (publickey)`. After few frustrating hours we found that it is to do with ssh private key(id_rsa) passphrase and we regenerated sshkeys without passphrase and finally we are able to run the app with out any issues. But I think it is not safe to have ssh keys without passphrase. Now my question is, is there any command/hack that can ignore the passphrase prompt (which is used for creation ssh keys`id_rsa` , `id_rsa.pub`) ? Because  I want to create my keys with passphrase but I want docker to ignore it and get into bitbucket to install my private repo. below are the steps we followed.

```
1. generate ssh keys using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C 
   "your_email@example.com"` 
2. this will prompt for passphrase (optional)
3. if you provide passphrase it will create your sshkyes with encryption
4. else your key will be without encryption
5. create a folder in your local machine (e.g. keys)
6. Use bash script (create a bash file in your repo)  to copy your 
   keys from local folder into a repository folder ( e.g sshkeys) as 
   shown below
      if [[ -f "/keys/id_rsa" ]]; then
        echo "keys exists!"
        cp -r /keys/. sshkeys/
       exit 0
      fi  

7. make sure you have git and ssh installed in your docker if not use 
   below command 

   apt-get install -y git ssh

8. And then in your docker file add the below code to copy sshkeys to
   docker root/.ssh

      RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      ADD sshkeys/. /root/.ssh/
      RUN chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
9. That's it, these steps are enough to install private repo and run it 
   in docker
```

**Question :** How to avoid passphrase prompt in docker and install the repo ?  I have tried most of the options suggested in **stackoverflow** and **github** but nothing seems helping me to skip passphrase prompt in docker.

Comment: Are you looking for ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -P '' ? (Note that that is two single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

You can always remove the keys again later on... but why not clone the repo from the build host first?

**Option 1**
Clone or pull the files you want with a script to the host:

```
git clone ssh://git@myhost.com/myrepo.git
```

Then in your Dockerfile:

```
COPY myrepo /
```

**Option 2**
Generate a new key and assign it to a user that has read only access, then copy this key into the image. On the host:

```
ssh-keygen -f k1 -t rsa -b 2048 -P ''
```

Then in the Dockerfile

```
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
COPY id_rsa* /root/.ssh/
RUN echo -e "Host: myhost.com\nStrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
RUN git clone ssh://git@myhost.com/myrepo.git
RUN rm -rf /root/.ssh  # remove the keys from the image
```

You can of course also check

```
man ssh_config
```

and

```
man ssh
```

For more options, such as using host keys instead of user keys, using different paths and names for the keys, or specifying them on the command line.

Also

```
man ssh-keygen
```

Of course. This shows that inside the container, for a set of universally compatible keys, you can do:

```
ssh-keygen -A
```